# how to remove imageview in an activity with fragment android

Tags: android, fragment

here is my code as follows for fragment:
This fragment is going to be called in MainActivity

```
 public class StylePreviewFragments extends Fragment{
        private CustomImageView ivPhoto;
        Intent intent;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.choosephoto,container,false);
            initialiseViews(view);
            return view;

        }
        private void initialiseViews(View view) {
            ivPhoto = (CustomImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivGalleryPhoto);

            ivPhoto.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(ShowCapturedPictureActivity.path)));

          }
    }
```

Mainactivity code:
 It contains imageview which i have to replace with fragments .ImageView added with custom id

```
public class ShowCapturedPictureActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_ID = 10101010;

            StylePreviewFragments stylepreviewfragmnets;
            public static  String path;
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.picturepreviiew);

                iv_showImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_ShowImage);
                intent=getIntent();
                path=intent.getExtras().get("imagepath").toString();
                // adding cutom id to imageview 
                iv_showImage.setId(CONTENT_VIEW_ID);
                callfragment();// calling fragment
            }

        public void callfragment() // replacing imageview with fragments
                {
                     stylepreviewfragmnets = new StylePreviewFragments();
                   FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    ft.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID,stylepreviewfragmnets);
                    ft.commit();
                }

            }
```

Comment: I don't think you can add a fragment to ImageView. Maybe you can define two view in your picturepreviiew, one is ImageView, the other is FragmentLayout. And when you only need ImageView, you make FragmentLayout invisible, otherwise make ImageView invisible.

Comment: show your `picturepreviiew` layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry ,what i was doing putting the fragments inside view, that is incorrect ,i should have put inside viewgroup. so i make imageview child of linear layout then i replace fragment with that linear layout. It works like a charm.

```
ft.add(linearlayout.getId(),stylepreviewfragmnets);
 ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

- put yourImageView `ImageView` inside `FrameLayout` yourContainer
- in your `callfragment()`, set yourImageView with visibility `View.GONE`, then add `stylepreviewfragmnets` into `FrameLayout` yourContainer

Hope this help!